# move richtext with mouse movement in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events, flex4, mousemove

i have a richText with background and i want to move this with mouse movement

so i write the code below:(richText is a global field)

```
public function createRichText(textPoint:Point):RichText {
richText = new RichText();  
    var measure:String = correlationMeasure.toFixed(4).toString();
    richText.text = measure;
    richText.x = textPoint.x; 
    richText.y = textPoint.y; 
    richText.width = 60;
    richText.height = 24;
    richText.setStyle("fontSize", 11);
    richText.setStyle("horizontalCenter", "0");
    richText.setStyle("verticalCenter", "1");
    richText.setStyle("left", "2");
    richText.setStyle("right", "2");
    richText.setStyle("top", "5");
    richText.setStyle("bottom", "5");
    richText.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
    richText.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
    richText.setStyle("backgroundColor", 0xe6e91f);
    richText.setStyle("backgroundAlpha", 1);
        richText.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler, false, 10);
        richText.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler, false, 10);
return richText
}


private function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    e.stopPropagation();
    allowDraging = true;
    richText.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragWithMouse);
}
private function dragWithMouse(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (allowDraging) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var temp:Point = richText.contentToGlobal(new Point(e.localX, e.localY));
        mousePoint = rootComponent.globalToLocal(temp);

        removeChild(richText);
        addChild(createRichText(mousePoint));
        e.updateAfterEvent();*/
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work correctly ... means it doesn't move continuously with mouse movement and have jump !!! anyone knows why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [startDrag()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag%28%29) and [stopDrag()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#stopDrag%28%29) methods defined in the `Sprite` class:

```
  private function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
      e.stopPropagation();
      richText.stopDrag();
  }

  private function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
       e.stopPropagation();
       richText.startDrag();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Pan it's working ... but i have problem i draw a line connector between two rectangle and this richText is in middle of that line... do you know how to move the line with this richText?

Comment: Try to put the richText and line in a container like a sprite, canvas etc, then add mouse event to the container,just as above

Comment: sorry @Pan i have a problem again: if i use a Canvas because my line is of type Shape, when i use myCanvas.addChild(myLine) give me a runtime error and if i use Sprite, it doesn't show my richText even by mySprite.addChild(richText) !!! isn't it weird?!

Comment: If you use canvas, you can add shape like this myCanvas.rawChildren.addChild(myLine);